# Truncated output of varchar(500) variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I'm trying to get two pieces of information from the following cursor: 
1. Subdomain
2. Domain ID

This scripts works well, except that the output of subdomain is just a single and the first letter.
So let's say that the subdomain for domain ID 2 is "abc.123domain.com", my result is "a".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Should I be using a different data type?

```
USE testDatabase

declare @sql nvarchar(500)
declare @domainID int
declare @subDomain nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)


declare domainIDCursor CURSOR

FOR 
    select domainID from tblDOMAINS

    OPEN domainIDCursor

    FETCH next from domainIDCursor into @domainID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                set @sql = N' use tblDOMAIN' + convert(nvarchar, @domainID) + @NewLineChar  +
                + ' select @subDomain = (select subDomain from tblLocalDomainInfo (nolock))'

                    execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@subDomain nvarchar output', @subDomain output

                print 'subDomain is ' + @subDomain + ' and the domainID is ' + convert(nvarchar,@domainID)


        FETCH NEXT from domainIDCursor into @domainID
        END

CLOSE domainIDCursor
DEALLOCATE domainIDCursor
```

Comment: Why are you saying `CONVERT(NVARCHAR` without specifying a length? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I've corrected that as well. Great blog entry!

Comment: Fixed here: execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@ subDomain nvarchar(200) output', @ subDomain output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a size here `convert(nvarchar, @domainID)` or here `N'@subDomain nvarchar output'`.

- If you declare a nvarchar variable without specifying a size it will default to nvarchar(1).
- If you cast/convert to nvarchar without specifying a size it will default to varchar(30).

Comment: But does that matter in this context? Since I'm trying to get the value of subDomain and not domainID.

Comment: Okay, you pointed me in the right direction. Fixed here:
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@ subDomain nvarchar(200) output', @ subDomain output

Comment: Also `N'@subDomain nvarchar output'` should have a size.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here:-

```
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@subDomain nvarchar output', @subDomain output
```

It should be

```
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@subDomain nvarchar(200) output', @subDomain output
```

Also see

```
declare @ID int
Set @ID = 1000

Select CONVERT(varchar, @ID) --output 1000
Select CONVERT(nvarchar, @ID) --output 1000
```